# How do I customize cors in Strapi v4

Tags: strapi

Details
  
  - **Strapi Version**: v4
  - **Node Version**: 16
  - **NPM Version**: 6.14.16
  - **Yarn Version**: 1.22.19

---

Neither of these solutions has worked. I am able to successfully make requests from localhost:3000. Which I do not want to be possible I only want to be able to get requests from my chosen url's. I don't know why this is really hard to find in the docs, but any help is appreciated.

I just want to limit my cors to a few URLs.

### I've tried:

*in config/server*

```js
  settings: {
    cors: {
      enabled: false,
      origin: ["http://test.com"],
    },
  },
```

*In config/middleware.js*

```js
  { name: "stapi::cors", config: { origin: ["http://test.com"] } },
```

Answer (score 0):

## In the following file:

*./config/middlewares.js*

```js
  {
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      origin: ['https://example.com', 'https://subdomain.example.com', 'https://someotherwebsite.org'],
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
      headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'Accept'],
      keepHeaderOnError: true,
    },
  },
```